# Multiplying Polynomial Coefficients in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like a general Excel method for multiplying polynomials. But I don't want to evaluate the polynomial yet, x is actually an imaginary number. I know how to use complex numbers in Excel, I already have a spreadsheet that evaluates equations given the polynomial coefficients. But, in Electrical Engineering, the starting point is usually a set of factored polynomials that need to be multiplied out first before my spreadsheet will work.

Example, starting with:

```
m2*x^2 + m1*x^1 + m0*x^0 and
n2*x^2 + n1*x^1 + n0*x^0
```

Multiplying these two gives:

```
m2*n2*x^4 + (m2*n1+m1*n2)*x^3 + (m2*n0+m1*n1+m0*n2)*x^2 + (m1*n0+m0*n1)*x^1 + m0*n0*x^0
```

So, given m2 ... m0, and n2 ... n0

I want to know p4 ... p0, where:

```
p4 = m2*n2
p3 = m2*n1 + m1*n2
p2 = m2*n0 + m1*n1 + m0*n2 
p1 = m1*n0 + m0*n1
p0 = m0*n0
```

Hopefully, you can see the pattern. Of course, I would like a general method for larger polynomials.

I could brute-force it, since the largest I would probably encounter would be four polynomials of order 2 (x^2), but there should be a more elegant method.

I would rather not use Visual Basic, since I want to share this when I am done, and people are paranoid about VBA spreadsheets.

Using many rows and columns for intermediate results is allowable. I would prefer to have the result in a row with p0 on the right side (p8 ... p0). If the method naturally gives another format, I am sure that I can transform it to what I need.

Edit:  Here is a brute force solution. Not as general purpose as I would like, but it will meet my needs for now.

[image]

Comment: I played around with matrix calculations a couple of years ago in excel, perhaps that would do it for you too.

Comment: @gns100 - A matrix multiply could be the first step, then add the diagonals of the matrix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the inspiration of the commenters, I have have a matrix-multiplication solution.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Matrix Multiplication]

The polynomial on the left side of each matrix is put into its columns. Then the matrix is multiplied by the polynomial on the right side using the `MMULT()` function. The Intermediate Result column shows the polynomial constants (the lowest nonzero constant is s^0).

The trick was writing the formula to fill out the matrix. It looks like this:

```
=IF(Row-Col+1 > 0, INDEX(Polynomial_1, Row-Col+1, 1), 0)
```

It uses the `Row` and `Col` numbers along both sides of the matrix to index into the polynomial constants.

Once the matrix multiplication is done, you can use the output from it as the input polynomial to the next matrix, as many times as you need.

I used [FormulaChop](https://formulachop.com) to generate this formula. (Full Disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6CG4.png) is a link the a screenshot of the output. [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=60137956841118689462) is a link to download the spreadsheet I built for this answer.

Comment: Although your post might answer the question it's very difficult - if not impossible - to replicate it. Please share more details, including the exact formulas to help understanding it.

Comment: You can download the spreadsheet I built using the last link in my answer.

Comment: Regardless, here is brief explanation: You can see that the first matrix is just the values in column B, where it has been shifted down in each column. 

Doing a matrix multiplication with this matrix (using `MMULT()`), and the values in column L has the effect that OP asked for, and the result is in column N.

Column N is then the input into the next matrix, so you can see it's gotten the same treatment as column B. Column Z holds the matrix multiplication of the 2nd matrix and the values in column X.

You'll see the result column values match the ones in OP's screenshot

Comment: @FormulaChop - Excellent, this is the kind of inspiration that I was looking for. Let me digest this some before I accept.

Comment: "You can download the spreadsheet" - answers need to be self containing, links can break and your answer will become much less useful.